# To have the matched value selected in populated PHP drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have managed to create populated drop down list through php taken from MySQL. Code #1

```
// START FUNCTION: create a drop down list containing area options from saved area in database
function create_dropdown_areanames() {
    global $wpdb;
    $output = '';
    $tbl_ads = $wpdb->prefix . "awpcp_areas";

    $query="SELECT DISTINCT area_name FROM ".$tbl_ads." WHERE area_name <> '' ORDER by area_name ASC";
    $res = awpcp_query($query, __LINE__);

    $listofsavedareas = array();
    while ($rsrow=mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
        $listofsavedareas[] = $rsrow[0];
    }
    $savedareaslist = $listofsavedareas;

    foreach ($savedareaslist as $savedarea) {
        $output .= "<option value=\"" . esc_attr($savedarea) . "\">" . stripslashes($savedarea) . "</option>";
    }
    return $output;
}
// END FUNCTION: create a drop down list containing area options from saved area in database
```

then I called this function through Code #2

```
        $allareas = create_dropdown_areanames($adcontact_country);
```

then I display it in the page throu Code #3

```
$theformbody.="<select name=\"adarea\" onchange=\"changeareameo();\" id='add_new_ad_area'><option value=\"\">";
$theformbody.=__("Area","AWPCP");
$theformbody.="</option>$allareas</select></p>";
```

I want to add the code below into Code #1

```
$output .= "<option selected='selected' value=\"" . esc_attr($savedarea) . "\">" . stripslashes($savedarea) . "</option>";
```

so when firing the function $allareas = create_dropdown_areanames($adcontact_country); **IF** the $adcontact_country variable matches with database string it would be the one selected on the drop down list and else the drop down list is generated from top to bottom. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I think you first would need to add a parameter to your function `create_dropdown_areanames()` then you can check it in the `foreach ($savedareaslist as $savedarea)`, and output the option selected if matched?

Comment: thanks for help @StrikeForceZero . that exactly what I needed and Michael gave it to me the easy way :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a ternary operator to the foreach.

```
 foreach ($savedareaslist as $savedarea) {
        $output .= "<option ".($savedarea==$adcontact_country?'selected="selected" ':'')."value=\"" . esc_attr($savedarea) . "\">" . stripslashes($savedarea) . "</option>";
    }
```

And add the variable to your function parameters

```
function create_dropdown_areanames($adcontact_country=null) {
```

Comment: thank you so much Michael. I was trying to find this out for the last 7 hours. I knew it should be simple but poor knowledge in php make it almost impossible to be solved. Your help is hugely appreciated.